# How to insert artificial data into a select statement

Tags: sql-server

Suppose we got a original query as follows:

```
SELECT A, B, C FROM tblA
```

Now, I need to additional artificial rows like 
**SELECT 'Kyala', B, C FROM tblA** when, for example, C = 100 to be inserted into the resultset.

As an example, if the tblA hold one row:

```
A      B      C
John   1      100
```

my goal is to return two rows like below with a single SQL query.

```
A      B      C
John   1      100
Kyala  1      100
```

How could I achieve it **using a single SQL** instead of relying on table variable or temp table?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Perhaps give an example of an initial condition, the operation you're doing, and the result you want? You've talked about "additional artificial rows" but then followed that with an example select, not quite clear what you need to do here. (Edit: Ah, Ian seems to have understood -- assuming he guessed right.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this with the [UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) operator.

```
SELECT A, B, C from tblA
UNION
SELECT 'Kyala', B, C FROM tblA WHERE C = 100
```

In response to the question in the comments about improving performance so that the table is only queried once - you could add a covering index over columns C and B so that the second part of the query uses that index rather than querying the table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tblA_CD] ON [dbo].[tblA] 
(
    [C] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [B]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

However, depending on the use case (this sounds like some kind of ad-hoc process for testing?), you might prefer to take the hit of two table scans rather than adding a new index which might not be appropriate for use in production.

Comment: Are you sure? It asks for additional rows, not additional columns. It's not entirely clear, though!

Comment: UNION still introduces two table query. Can make it to query table merely once?

Comment: OK, see my edit above - I've suggested adding a covering index to the table to take care of the second part of the query.

Comment: He may not *want* a union, but I'd say he needs one. Nice touch with the index, Ian.

Answer (score 2):

Just refined the query to resolve error on Union:

```
SELECT A, B, C from tblA
UNION
SELECT 'Kyala' as A, B, C FROM tblA WHERE C = 100
```

And if you don't want the others where c=100 and still getting the A in the result (from the first Select in the union), you can do it like:

```
SELECT A, B, C from tblA WHERE C <> 100
UNION
SELECT 'Kyala', B, C FROM tblA WHERE C = 100
```

or

```
SELECT CASE(C)
           when 100 then 'Kyala'
           else A
       END as A, B, C from tblA
```

Comment: UNION still introduces two table query. Can make it to query table merely once?

Comment: So, you follow the last query without UNION but with CASE.

Comment: According to the question, he wants both the 'Kyala' and 'John' rows output. Not doable without the UNION.

Comment: In that case, go for the Union. I don't see other way out at this moment.

@Arne: Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CASE:

```
SELECT B, C, 
       CASE 
          WHEN C = 100 THEN 'Kyala'
          ELSE A
       END
FROM tblA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNIION statement:

```
SELECT A, B, C FROM tblA
UNION
SELECT 'Kyala', B, C FROM tblA WHERE C = 100
```

Comment: 2TomTom. There is nothing about absence of UNION in the question.

Answer (score -4):

> ```
> I need to additional artificial rows like SELECT 'Kyala', B, C FROM
> ```
>
> tblA when, for example, C = 100 to be
>   inserted into the resultset.

Now, read up on....
* IF in SQL Server
*SWITCH etc.

Basically, you can define an additional column as was shown

```
(SELECT 'test', A, B, C FROM...)
```

But instead of 'test' you can put in an if or switch and work with the other fields to determine the exact stuff to output.

```
SELECT IF (xxxx) AS FirstColumn, A, B,
C FROM ...
```

Comment: The OP asked for additional rows, not additional columns.